# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (Invalid Column Name '...') after modifying database when using Data Source on a listbox

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I just started developing my first application using Visual Studio. I have created my own SQL Server database and connected it to a listbox element using a Data Source which is working fine.

However I noticed that after modifying the Data Source (let's say removing a column) I get the error mentioned in the title, which makes perfect sense as obviously the column doesn't exist anymore. But how can I tell Visual Studio that it does not have to look for the removed column anymore?

After receiving the error, I only get directed to this line of code:

```
this.tableNameTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbNameDataSet.dbtable);
```

I can't really do anything with this. I've tried to look up the internet for several answers but I couldn't find someone who has encountered the same problem (probably because I used the wrong keywords).

Any advice? Thanks for helping me out!

Additional question: Is this called *DataBinding*?

Comment: Is manually writing code for that a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reconfigure the **TableAdapter** after any change in the schema:

[configure-a-tableadapters-fill-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-and-configure-tableadapters?view=vs-2019#configure-a-tableadapters-fill-method)

Even better, make the changes in the **TableAdapter** first and they'll be reflected to the database:

> Any changes that you make to the TableAdapter's main Fill method are reflected in the schema of the associated data table. For example, removing a column from the query in the main Fill method also removes the column from the associated data table. Additionally, removing the column from the main Fill method removes the column from any additional queries for that TableAdapter.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After I make changes (like deleting a column) my database does not apply those changes. Could you explain who it is supossed to "update" itself from changes made in the TableAdapter?

Comment: Once you are connected to the database, any changes you apply via Visual studio will be depicted on your database.